# Have a bash condition as an argument to the timeout function

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to create a oneliner to be run in terminal that would execute a condition for 60 seconds and then end it. I would like to use the timeout function.
You use the timeout function like this:
timeout 5s command
How can I encapsulate a "while do done" condition as to pass it to the timeout function?

Comment: Put your `while do done` alone in a script, save it to a file.  Then call timeout on that script.

Comment: `timeout 5s bash -c "while ...; do ...; done"`?